# How to force bias to zero in tensorflow LinearRegressor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm using the **tensorflow LinearRegressor** API for a regression problem (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor). I know the bias in my model is exactly 0.

How can I **force** LinearRegressor to learn a bias of 0?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
```

Simulate some data with 2 features (+ bias of 0)
y = 0 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + noise

```
np.random.seed(5332)
n = 1000
weights = np.array([
    [2],
    [3],
])

bias = 0

x = np.random.randn(n, np.shape(weights)[0])
y = (bias + np.matmul(x, weights) + np.random.randn(n, 1)).ravel()
```

In sklearn I would use fit_intercept=False to force the bias to 0:

```
ols = SGDRegressor(tol=0.000001, fit_intercept=False)
ols.fit(x, y)

print("True weights: {}".format(weights.ravel()))
print("Learned weights: {}".format(np.round(ols.coef_), 3))
print("True bias: {}".format([bias]))
print("Learned bias: {}".format(np.round(ols.intercept_), 3))
```

Output:

```
True weights: [2 3]
Learned weights: [2. 3.]
True bias: [0]
Learned bias: [0.]
```

In tensorflow I did the following:

```
column =  tf.feature_column.numeric_column('x', shape=np.shape(x)[1])
ols = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns=[column],
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)
)


train_input = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": x},
    y=y,
    shuffle=False,
    num_epochs=100,
    batch_size=int(len(y) / 20)
)

ols.train(train_input)

print("True weights: {}".format(weights.ravel()))
print("Learned weights: {}".format(np.round(ols.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/x/weights').flatten(), 3)))
print("True bias: {}".format([bias]))
print("Learned bias: {}".format(np.round(ols.get_variable_value('linear/linear_model/bias_weights').flatten(), 3)))
```

Output:

```
True weights: [2 3]
Learned weights: [1.993 2.998]
True bias: [0]
Learned bias: [-0.067]
```

But the learned bias should be: [0], how can I enforce this?

Comment: old question, but tf.keras.constraints is what you are searching for, right?

Answer (score 0):

i guess tf.keras.constraints is what you are searching for.